# Office365 API append email signatures based on senders email address

Tags: office365api

We are considering using Office365 API to send our emails. One reason we are considering Office365 is to be able to automatically apply signatures. So if we send automated email for a specific user, are we able to specify that we want the signature appended to that email?

Would we be required to use the user credentials for the user we are sending with, or are there Admin roles available allowing use to pick / automatically apply the correct email signature?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't choose/apply different signature when sending email to specific user with O365 API. As a workaround, with [outlook mail rest api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Createandsendmessages) ,you could create an email message , inserts an email signature into the end of email message body when sending to a specific user. You could use a HTML body for your email message,for example :

```
       // Create the email message text body.
       string htmlBodyTxt = @"<html><head></head><body><p>This is the email message body before a signature is added.</p>
                            </body></html>";

       // Identify the signature insertion point at the end of the HTML body.
       int signatureInsertPnt = htmlBodyTxt.IndexOf("</body>");

       // Create the email signature.
       string signature = "<p>Dallas Durkin<br/>Senior Planner<br/>Adventure Works Cycles</p>" +
                          "<p>4567 Main St.<br/>La Habra Heights, CA 90631</p><p>(323) 555-0100</p>";

       // Insert the signature into the HTML body.
       string newBody = htmlBodyTxt.Insert(signatureInsertPnt, signature);
```